# Trying to understand this retryWhen/scan/delay rxjs sequence

Tags: rxjs

So I came up with this implementation of a delayed retry for HTTP requests, this works fine and I have a good understanding of it as well.

```
retryWhen(err => {
    let retryCount = 0;
    let nextDelay = 0;
    backoff = backoff < 0 || backoff === null ? DEFAULT_BACKOFF : backoff;
    maxDelay = maxDelay < 0 || maxDelay === null ? DEFAULT_MAX_DELAY : maxDelay;

    return err.pipe(
      scan(idx => {
        if (idx > maxRetries - 1) {
          throw err;
        } else {
          idx++;
          retryCount = idx;
          nextDelay = Math.min(retryDelay + ((retryCount - 1) * backoff), maxDelay);

          return idx;
        }
      }, 0),
      tap(v => console.log(`Waiting ${nextDelay} ms for Retry #${retryCount}...`)),
      delay(nextDelay),
      tap(v => console.log(`Initiating HTTP Retry for context ${context}`))
    )
```

First issue: The above code works fine when I use a constant value in the delay operator like so `delay(3000)` but it does not when I use the `nextDelay` variable.  When I use the `nextDelay` variable there is no delay, it's like the variable is zero.

However the value is output correctly in the `tap` operator above it so I know it's in scope and the `let` is within scope of the `retryWhen` so should be good.  I can't figure out why the delay does not work unless I use a value literal.

Second issue: I want to optimize the above code so that I don't use the variables `retryCount` and `nextDelay`, I want to compute those on the fly within the `delay` operator, however this operator takes only the amount of the delay as the input and does not have a reference to the `idx` emmitted by the `scan` above.  I would like to do something like this:

```
scan(idx => ... code to either throw the error or emit the index ...),
delay(idx => Math.min(retryDelay + (idx - 1) * backoff), maxDelay)
```

The scan maps the original `err` element to the index `idx` but how exactly do I get that in the `delay` operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First issue: The above code works fine when I use a constant value in the delay operator like so delay(3000) but it does not when I use the nextDelay variable. When I use the nextDelay variable there is no delay, it's like the variable is zero.

The cause of the issue has been already pointed out in [fridoo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64621613/9632621).

> However the value is output correctly in the tap operator

This is a hint of you could fix it. The *difference* is that `delay(value)` *captures* the `value` and in the case of `tap(() => ...)`, the `value` will be evaluated every time its callback function will be invoked(in this case, on each `Next` notification).

If we take a look at [`delay`'s implementation](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/delay.ts#L55-L58)

```js
export function delay<T>(due: number | Date, scheduler: SchedulerLike = asyncScheduler): MonoTypeOperatorFunction<T> {
  const duration = timer(due, scheduler);
  return delayWhen(() => duration);
}
```

we'll see that it first *captures* the value in a `timer` observable, which will be then used with a `delayWhen`.

So, this first issue could be fixed with:

```js
/* ... */
tap(v => console.log(`Waiting ${nextDelay} ms for Retry #${retryCount}...`)),
delayWhen(() => timer(nextDelay)),
tap(v => console.log(`Initiating HTTP Retry for context ${context}`))
/* ... */
```

> Second issue: I want to optimize the above code so that I don't use the variables retryCount and nextDelay

We can use other RxJS operators for this:

```js
retryWhen(err => {
backoff = backoff < 0 || backoff === null ? DEFAULT_BACKOFF : backoff;
maxDelay = maxDelay < 0 || maxDelay === null ? DEFAULT_MAX_DELAY : maxDelay;

return err.pipe(
  // replacing `retryCount` with `map`'s index argument
  map((err, idx) => {
    // you can also throw the error here
    if (idx >= maxRetries) { throw err; }
    
    const retryCount = idx + 1;

    // returning the `nextDelay`
    return Math.min(retryDelay + ((retryCount - 1) * backoff), maxDelay);
  })
  delayWhen(nextDelay => timer(nextDelay)),
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  This really helped understand everything.  Appreciate it.

Comment: I’m glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

The function passed to `retryWhen` is only called once, on the first error. So `delay(nextDelay)` is called once when the `err.pipe(...)` observable is created (not when `err` emits). At that time `nextDelay` is still `0`. You should put all your logic in an operator that returns a different value depending on values emitted by `err`.

To return an observable that emits with a changing delay you can `mergeMap` to a `timer`. This should get you started:

```ts
interface RetryStrategyConfig {
  maxRetryAttempts?: number;
  scalingDuration?: number;
  maxDelay?: number;
  excludedStatusCodes?: number[];
}

function genericRetryStrategy({
  maxRetryAttempts = 6,
  scalingDuration = 1000,
  maxDelay = 5000,
  excludedStatusCodes = []
}: RetryStrategyConfig = {}) {
  return (attempts: Observable<any>) => {
    return attempts.pipe(
      mergeMap((error, i) => {
        const retryAttempt = i + 1;
        // if maximum number of retries have been met
        // or response is a status code we don't wish to retry, throw error
        if (
          retryAttempt > maxRetryAttempts ||
          excludedStatusCodes.find(e => e === error.status)
        ) {
          return throwError(error);
        }

        const nextDelay = Math.min(retryAttempt * scalingDuration, maxDelay);
        console.log(`Attempt ${retryAttempt}: retrying in ${nextDelay}ms`);
        return timer(nextDelay);
      }),
      finalize(() => console.log("We are done!"))
    );
  };
}

obs$.pipe(
  retryWhen(genericRetryStrategy())
)
```

Comment: Thank you!  That helped answer the question, did not think of that... now it's apparent after you pointed it out :)  Rx can get really confusing sometimes...